# JOIN not working with PHP + ODBC + Microsoft Access

Tags: php, sql, ms-access, odbc

I am trying to write a PHP script that plugs into an existing Access Database. If I would be starting from scratch, I would have used MySQL for the job, but because there is an existing MS Access application I am stuck with the database as it is.

As of right now, I am trying to get the following PHP Code to work.

```
$conn=odbc_connect('buju','','');
if (!$conn)
{
  exit("Connection Failed: " . $conn);
}

$sql="SELECT * 
      FROM Teilnehmer 
      INNER JOIN TeilnWerte ON Teilnehmer.LfdNr = TeilnWerte.Teilnehmer 
      WHERE Teilnehmer.Klasse = '$_POST[klasse]'";
$rs=odbc_exec($conn,$sql);

echo "\nErrorCode:\n".odbc_error($conn);
echo "\nErrorMessage:\n".odbc_errormsg($conn);
```

I am pretty sure, that the problem is in the SQL Query, since it all works fine if I only do

```
SELECT * FROM Teilnehmer WHERE Klasse = '$_POST[klasse]'
```

without trying to join the second table.

I am using odbc and the Microsoft Access Driver. The Error Code that I get is `07001`. The Error Message is

```
[Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Too few parameters. Expected 1.
```

I have also tried

```
SELECT * 
FROM Teilnehmer, TeilnWerte 
WHERE Teilnehmer.LfdNr = TeilnWerte.Teilnehmer 
  AND Teilnehmer.Klasse = '$_POST[klasse]'
```

which did not work either.

Is there anything that I am doing wrong? Are there certain SQL commands that don't work

Comment: I actually have. Just left `echo $sql;` and a few other parts out for better readability.

Output is exactly what I expected: `SELECT * FROM Teilnehmer INNER JOIN TeilnWerte ON Teilnehmer.LfdNr = TeilnWerte.Teilnehmer WHERE Teilnehmer.Klasse = '06A'`

Comment: Googling this error message shows that it typically comes up when one of the field names in the query is incorrect. What happens when you try the query `SELECT Teilnehmer FROM TeilnWerte`?

Comment: Some older versions of Access can sometimes be particular about parentheses around your JOINs.  Not sure if that's the case, but thought I'd mention it.

Comment: Ok it was my mistake. When I open up a view that shows the Table in Access, only Teilnehmer is shown, even though it is actually named Teilnehmernummer. Since Teilnehmer is a full German word, I didn't expect the title to be any longer and thus didn't make the column wider.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `echo $sql` gives you ...

```sql
SELECT *
FROM
    Teilnehmer
    INNER JOIN TeilnWerte
    ON Teilnehmer.LfdNr = TeilnWerte.Teilnehmer
WHERE Teilnehmer.Klasse = '06A'
```

Test that same statement as a new query in Access.  Create a query in the query designer, switch to SQL View, paste in the statement and see what happens when you run it.

Most often the cause of *"Too few parameters"* is a misspelled item (object name, function or SQL keyword).  Since the db engine can't find that item, it assumes the item is a parameter.  Access  will pop up a parameter dialog asking you to supply a parameter value, and that dialog also contains the parameter's name.  So it tells you which is the misspelled item.